# Hive and Hadoop Running Only Locally

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have configured a 3 node Hadoop cluster. I was trying to use Hive on top of it. Hive always seems to running only in local mode. I heard that Hive takes values from Hadoop about the cluster. So I ran a job in Hadoop and it seems to be running in Local mode as well. I have installed Hive on all three nodes as well.I'm attaching the logs and configuration files. Please ask me if you need any further details.

### Hive Log:

```
INFO  : Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
INFO  : In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
INFO  : In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
INFO  :   set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
INFO  : In order to set a constant number of reducers:
INFO  :   set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
INFO  : number of splits:1
INFO  : Submitting tokens for job: job_local49819314_0002
INFO  : The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
INFO  : Job running in-process (local Hadoop)
INFO  : 2016-01-27 23:56:30,389 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
INFO  : Ended Job = job_local49819314_0002
```

### Hadoop Word Count Log:

```
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local494116460_0001
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local494116460_0001
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local494116460_0001_m_000000_0
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://master:9000/exercise3:0+18834811
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
16/01/27 23:46:20 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
16/01/27 23:46:21 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local494116460_0001 running in uber mode : false
16/01/27 23:46:21 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:27 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 13% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:29 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:30 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 19% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:32 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 29% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:35 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:36 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 36% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:38 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:39 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 45% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:41 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:42 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 54% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:44 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:45 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 62% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:46 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map > map
16/01/27 23:46:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
16/01/27 23:46:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
16/01/27 23:46:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 21289849; bufvoid = 104857600
16/01/27 23:46:46 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 23806260(95225040); length = 2408137/6553600
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local494116460_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local494116460_0001_m_000000_0' done.
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local494116460_0001_m_000000_0
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for reduce tasks
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: File Output Committer Algorithm version is 1
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.ReduceTask: Using ShuffleConsumerPlugin: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.reduce.Shuffle@15602819
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: MergerManager: memoryLimit=333971456, maxSingleShuffleLimit=83492864, mergeThreshold=220421168, ioSortFactor=10, memToMemMergeOutputsThreshold=10
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0 Thread started: EventFetcher for fetching Map Completion Events
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.LocalFetcher: localfetcher#1 about to shuffle output of map attempt_local494116460_0001_m_000000_0 decomp: 13082052 len: 13082056 to MEMORY
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.InMemoryMapOutput: Read 13082052 bytes from map-output for attempt_local494116460_0001_m_000000_0
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: closeInMemoryFile -> map-output of size: 13082052, inMemoryMapOutputs.size() -> 1, commitMemory -> 0, usedMemory ->13082052
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.EventFetcher: EventFetcher is interrupted.. Returning
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 1 / 1 copied.
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: finalMerge called with 1 in-memory map-outputs and 0 on-disk map-outputs
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 13082040 bytes
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merged 1 segments, 13082052 bytes to disk to satisfy reduce memory limit
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 1 files, 13082056 bytes from disk
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO reduce.MergeManagerImpl: Merging 0 segments, 0 bytes from memory into reduce
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 13082040 bytes
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 1 / 1 copied.
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
16/01/27 23:46:47 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/01/27 23:46:53 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:46:53 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 85%
16/01/27 23:46:56 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:46:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 89%
16/01/27 23:46:59 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:46:59 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 92%
16/01/27 23:47:02 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:47:02 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 96%
16/01/27 23:47:05 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:47:05 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 99%
16/01/27 23:47:08 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:47:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/01/27 23:47:11 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0' to hdfs://master:9000/output/_temporary/0/task_local494116460_0001_r_000000
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0' done.
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local494116460_0001_r_000000_0
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce task executor complete.
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local494116460_0001 completed successfully
16/01/27 23:47:18 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 35
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=26711328
    FILE: Number of bytes written=40348644
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=37669622
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=12758437
    HDFS: Number of read operations=13
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=4
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=65535
    Map output records=602035
    Map output bytes=21289849
    Map output materialized bytes=13082056
    Input split bytes=93
    Combine input records=602035
    Combine output records=58349
    Reduce input groups=58349
    Reduce shuffle bytes=13082056
    Reduce input records=58349
    Reduce output records=58349
    Spilled Records=116698
    Shuffled Maps =1
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=1
    GC time elapsed (ms)=123
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=848297984
Shuffle Errors
    BAD_ID=0
    CONNECTION=0
    IO_ERROR=0
    WRONG_LENGTH=0
    WRONG_MAP=0
    WRONG_REDUCE=0
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=18834811
File Output Format Counters 
    Bytes Written=12758437
```

## Configuration Files

The same configuration is present in all the systems

### mapred-site.xml

```
  <configuration>  
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
  <value>master:5431</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
  <value>/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop_tmp/history/intermediate</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
  <value>/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop_tmp/history/done</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
  <value>master:54311</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
  <value>master:50030</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

### yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

### hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

### core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

### Bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_66
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
# -- HADOOP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES START -- #
export HADOOP_HOME=/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_CONF=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
# -- HADOOP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES END -- #

# -- Hive Variables Start --#
export HIVE_HOME=/home/huser/apache-hive-1.2.1-bin
export HIVE_CONF=$HIVE_HOME/conf
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/lib:$PATH
export ANT_LIB=/home/huser/apache-ant-1.9.6/lib
# -- Hive Variables End -- #
```

### hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://master/metastore</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hive</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value></value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
  <value>thrift://master:9083</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.tracker</name>
  <value>master:5431</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

### Hive Properties

```
Set hive.exec.mode.local.auto;
    +----------------------------------+--+
    |               set                |
    +----------------------------------+--+
    | hive.exec.mode.local.auto=false  |
    +----------------------------------+--+
set mapred.job.tracker;
    +----------------------------------+--+
    |               set                |
    +----------------------------------+--+
    | mapred.job.tracker=master:54311  |
    +----------------------------------+--+
```

start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh 
start all the datanodes, namenode, resourcemanager etc. The cluster is working fine the problem seems to be only with the jobs. I can see that all the datanodes are available at http://master:50070 and a job history page at http://master:8088

If you need any further logs or config files let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the mapred-site.xml.
This is the new file

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir</name>
    <value>/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop_tmp/history/intermediate</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir</name>
    <value>/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/hadoop_tmp/history/done</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
  <value>master:54311</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.http.address</name>
  <value>master:50030</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

The `mapreduce.job.tracker` seems to be not a valid property.
and I have also changed my 
`HADOOP_HOME=/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1/` to 
`HADOOP_HOME=/home/huser/hadoop-2.7.1` removing the forward slash `(/)`.

I have also changes the hive-site.xml to the following:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://master/metastore</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
      <value>hive</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
      <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
      <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
      <value>thrift://master:9083</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```